# why wont function testIfIdExist load page before continue onto next instruction

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, settimeout

here is all the my code

```
var dublist = [];
var linkList = [];
var lodeIn;

function testIfIdExist(){
    var currentAnime;

       for(var ia = 0; ia < linkList.length - 1 ; ia++) {

        console.log('http://www.ryuanime.com'+ linkList[ia])
        window.location = 'http://www.ryuanime.com'+ linkList[ia]
        lodeIn = setTimeout(function(){console.log('http://www.ryuanime.com'+ linkList[ia])}, 1500); 

        var element = document.evaluate( '//*[@id="anime-episode-list-dub"]/li[1]' ,document, null,                     XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
            if (element != null) {

                var currentAnime = document.evaluate( '//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/h1' ,document, null,                     XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.outerHTML;

                var X = currentAnime.length - 5;
                dublist.push(currentAnime.substring(5,X))

            }
        }
            loopdublist()

}





function loopAnlist(){
    var longAssString = document.getElementById("animeList").outerHTML;
    var linkstart = 1;
    var linkend = 1;
    var i = 0;

    do {
        linkstart = longAssString.search('<a href="');

        longAssString = longAssString.substring(linkstart+9,longAssString.length)
        var linkend = longAssString.search('">');

        linkList.push(longAssString.substring(0,linkend))

        longAssString = longAssString.substring(linkend+2,longAssString.length)

    } while (linkstart >= 1);
    testIfIdExist()
}

loopAnlist()








function loopAnlistArray(){
    for(var i = 0; i < linkList.length - 1 ; i++) {
        console.log(linkList[i])
    }
}




function loopdublist(){
    for(var i = 0; i < linkList.length - 1 ; i++) {
        console.log(dublist[i])
    }
}
```

I seem to just skip over window.location and only runs it after it has run every thing else.

I need the code to go to the link check if the xpath exist, if so add the page header to another array, then move on to the next link in the array and do the same to the end of the array.

Comment: If it did load the page, then you have another problem: the next instruction wouldn't be executed, because the page that the script is in has been replaced. Maybe take a look at [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: im running it with this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo